# How to implement number of profile visit and restrict in a day in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, count

I developing a website for job portal in cakephp, i want to restrict employer to visit resume of only 15 profile in a day,and the next day he again visit 15 profile,after it we stop him to visit and show maximum limit message.i have user_id,Employer Id,job id but unable to think how to implement counter on certain employer id,can anyone suggest how to implement in brief.if you have any doubts please ask me.

Comment: Show some code or what you have tried so for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate table **profile_views** to contain Profile views related data.

**profile_views** would contain id, user_id, viewer_id, no_profile_views, profile_view_datetime.

Every time the page loads, you need to insert(for first record) and update the table by incrementing no_profile_views by 1.

You need to run a query to check the no. of profile views of each user corresponding to viewer_id.

Finally, when the number reaches 15, you could redirect the user and show a custom message.

I'd suggest you to write this logic within afterFilter() function in the controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, otherwise it's very difficult to assist.

Comment: i have a dashboard of employer where he can see all profile of jobseeker in listing i want to show all profile but when he visits profile able to view only 15 profile.